# Using the function fread() to read blocks of data in a file

Tags: c++

If I use

```
size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream ),
```

how can I derefence the data pointed by ptr?. Like if I have

```
int main()
{
void *ptr
fread(ptr,1,100,file);
printf("%s",ptr);
}
```

Comment: In what format is the data you are reading? (Also, you can't pass the value of `ptr` to `fread` until you assign it a value!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand the purpose of `void * ptr` in the declaration of `fread`.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread

> buffer     -   pointer to the array where the read objects are stored

First, the argument must be a valid pointer where objects can be stored. Using

```
void *ptr;
fread(ptr,1,100,file);
```

will lead to undefined behavior since `ptr` does not point to anything valid.

Second, the reason for the argument type is `void*` to allow you to read all kinds of data from a stream. E.g.

```
// Read an integer
int i;
fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, file);

// Read 10 integers
int a[10];
fread(a, sizeof(int), 10, file);

// Read a double
double d;
fread(&d, sizeof(double), 1, file);
```